# Checking if a string value is equal to - (minus symbol)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table. Inside the table, the `td`'s either have `--` `-` `+-` `+` or `++` as their content.

I'm trying to add a class to the `td` element, depending on which symbol it contains.

The `td`'s with `+` and `++` are working just fine, but my code doesn't seem to be checking the `-` symbol properly, even after escaping (`\-`).

Am I missing something obvious here?

I have an example Pen here: https://codepen.io/lukeseager/pen/PowgNJE

The JS I have is:

```
var tds = $('body').find('td');

    tds.each(function() {

        var td = $(this);
        var value = td.text(); 

        if( value === "\-\-"  ) {
            td.addClass('minus-minus');
        } else if( value === "\-"  ) {
            td.addClass('minus');
        } else if( value === "+\-"  ) {
            td.addClass('plus-minus');
        } else if( value === "+"  ) {
            td.addClass('plus');
        } else if( value === "++"  ) {
            td.addClass('plus-plus');
        }

    });
```

and a simplified HTML structure is:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>test </th>
     <th>test </th>
     <th>test </th>
     <th>test</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>+-</td>
      <td>++</td>
      <td>–</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>+</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The minus sign in the table is `–` (EN dash, code: 8211), not the regular one

Comment: Why are you escaping the dashes?

Comment: you don't need to scape it, just clear the signs and type they again. Looks like the signs are in a different format.

Comment: I was just testing escaping the dashes because just typing === "--" wasn't working either.

Comment: Looking like typo, still you can do `if( value == "-" || value == "–"  )`

Comment: Best to compare again `\u2013` so that it's explicit that you're comparing against a Unicode character that's very hard to visibly distinguish from the ASCII hyphen, e.g. `if (value === '-' || value === '\u2013') { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `-` character in the `td` tag is different from the `-` character inside your js code.

So, you just need to copy the `-` character from your `td` tag and replace it with `-` character in:

```
if(value === "–") {...}
```

and

```
if(value === "+-") {...}
```

Comment: As a (maybe) easier way to visually detect the different dash in code, consider doing something like `EN_DASH = String.fromCharCode(8211)` and then using `EN_DASH`. If you're looking at this code a few months from now or if it's somebody else, the difference between  `"-"` and `"–"` is very hard to spot.

Comment: or use `\u2013`

Comment: Copying the outputted characters worked. I was typing in the same symbol in my table as in my JS, but this was in the WordPress editor, so maybe it alters the symbol for some reason before it outputs.

Comment: I think to simplify the code I'd just do `value = value.replace(/\u2013/g', '-')` to normalize the string and then just compare against hyphens in the usual way.   Alternatively, fix the site to prevent the Unicode en-dash from appearing in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

You can use this
var ifExists = "your string".slice("-").length > 0;